# Meteor Velocity Jasmine: Prevent beforeEach Global Scope Across Describes

Tags: meteor, coffeescript, jasmine, meteor-velocity

In my Meteor app, I have a form at `/join` with a disabled button. I test this disabled state with the following integration test file:

```
// tests/jasmine/client/integration/user/joinSpec.js.coffee

describe 'user', ->

  describe 'join', ->

    beforeEach ->
      Router.go 'join_path'

    it 'is unsubmittable by default', ->
      expect($('#join-submit')).toHaveAttr 'disabled', 'disabled'
```

I also have a form at `/signup` with a disabled button. I test that disabled state with this additional integration test file:

```
// tests/jasmine/client/integration/user/signupSpec.js.coffee

describe 'user', ->

  describe 'signup', ->

    beforeEach ->
      Router.go 'signup_path'

    it 'is unsubmittable by default', ->
      expect($('#signup-submit')).toHaveAttr 'disabled', 'disabled'
```

Both tests pass independently of each other (i.e. when only one file exists). However, the `user.signup` test only passes in absense of the `user.join` test, I assume due to the way Meteor executes the files in order by filename.

It seems like `beforeEach` has global scope, and the one from `user.join` is overriding the one in `user.signup`, causing the sign up test to execute on the wrong route and fail. Any idea why this is, or how to lock it down to local scope?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Iron Router. Refer to the following article for resolution: https://meteor-testing.readme.io/docs/jasmine-integration-tests-with-iron-router